# OO programming in javascript: is it good practice to have attributes being objects themselves?

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

I've created some objects with Backbone the way I'm used to do in Java.

```
var Lead = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        lng: 0,
        lat: 0,
        distance: 0
    },
    initialize: function () {

    }
});

var Leads = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Lead
});

var Map = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        leads: null
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.set("leads",new Leads());
    },
    addJson: function (json) {

        var key;

        for (key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                var lead = new Lead({ lng: parseFloat(json[key].lng.replace(",", ".")), lat: parseFloat(json[key].lat.replace(",", ".")), distance: json[key].distance });
                this.attributes.leads.add(lead);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, the attribute leads of an object Map is a Collection Leads when it's created. However, this doesn't work as well as in Java as I'm forced to use:

```
this.attributes.leads
```

to call one of the method of the attribut leads.

**Question:**

Is it bad practice to use objects as attributes, and if yes what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to do `this.get('leads').add(lead)` in your loop; `this.get('leads)` in this case will return (a reference to) the `leads` collection which has the `add()` method. You can't do `this.leads.add` because `this.leads` doesn't exist.

Backbone's `this.attributes` is a convenient way of getting all the attributes of a model, however `this.set()` and `this.get()` are preferred as interfaces as events are fired when these are called.

Comment: Thx, that does look cleaner.